# Continuity problem involving piecewise function and glue points

Tags: calculus, continuity

Determine all values of the constant a such that the function f(x) below is continuous at the glue point.

$$f(x)= \{ \frac{ax}{tanx}, x>0; a^2-2,x\leqslant0$$

I tried to do many things like setting them equal to each other, and graphing the functions with different values of a

Comment: Have you determined the upper limit of $f$ in zero?

Comment: I don't know what upper limit of f means. could you possibly explain?

Comment: Just examine the limit $f(x_k)$ for $x_k\to 0$ and $x_k>0 \forall k$. If this doesn't sound familiar to you, maybe it helps to use the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity. For this you probably need some estimates on $\tan(x)$.

Comment: I still don't understand unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the function to be continuous at $x=0$, you need the left-hand and right-hand limits as $x\rightarrow0$ to be equal. Well...

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}(a^2-2)=a^2-2$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}\frac{ax}{\tan x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}(a\cdot\frac{x}{\sin x}\cdot\cos x)=a$$

So find the values of $a$ that make $a^2-2=a$.